# A possible generalization of "Group Cohomolgy"

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

The group cohomology of a group $G$ is defined as the derived functor associated to the following left exact functor:
$$FIX: \mathcal{M_G} \to \mathcal{Ab}$$
where $FIX$ is the functor from the category of $G$-modules to the category of Abelian groups sending each module $M$ to its subgroup consisting of all elements of $M$ which are fixed by $G$ action.

Now we fix a natural number $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and do an obvious generalization of the above construction:

Instead of the above left exact functor $FIX$ we consider the functor $P_n$ which send a $G$-midule $M$ to the following subgroup of $M$:
$$P_n(M)=\{x\in M \mid g.x= nx, \forall g \in G\}$$.

> In this way what would be the corresponding derived functor?What kind of cohomology theory would appear? Is this a trivial generalization of classical "Group Cohomology"?If not, what would be a topological analogy?

The later question is motivated by the fact that the group cohomology corresponds to singular cohomology of the corresponding Eilenberg-Mclane space)

Comment: This is just fixed points in the $(n-1)$-torsion of $M$, or else $\operatorname{Hom}_G(\mathbb Z/(n-1)\mathbb Z,M)$, with $\mathbb Z/(n-1)\mathbb Z$ having the trivial $G$-action; accordingly you will just get $\operatorname{Ext}$ for that module. It should be easy to relate this to a mixture of "ordinary" Ext and "ordinary" $G$-cohomology

Comment: Is $g\in G$ fixed?

Comment: @JulianRosen non $g\in G$ varies over $G$.I revise the question.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე thank you for your comment and your attention to the question.